# Unable to call ModelBinders in Program.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

why `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string), new TrimModelBinder());` is not getting run? my input value still have extra space. I just want to trim some input field when OnPost() / OnGet() gets called

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
...
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.

    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string), new TrimModelBinder());

    app.UseHsts();
 }

 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

TrimModelBinder class

```
public class TrimModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var shouldPerformRequestValidation = controllerContext.Controller.ValidateRequest && bindingContext.ModelMetadata.RequestValidationEnabled;
        var unvalidatedValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider as IUnvalidatedValueProvider;

        var value = unvalidatedValueProvider == null ?
          bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName) :
          unvalidatedValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName, !shouldPerformRequestValidation);

        var attemptedValue = value?.AttemptedValue;

        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attemptedValue) ? attemptedValue : attemptedValue.Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to add the model binder in model rather than in Program.cs.

Comment: thanks was able to make it work with model